# jQuery function that will remove specific word on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following information in a div

```
<div class="list">Abc, Test, Ready</div>
```

Below the div, I have this additional information

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Abc">Remove Abc</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Test">Remove Test</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Ready">Remove Ready</a>
```

I am trying to write a jQuery function that will remove either Abc, Test, Ready (and the comma if necessary) when you click on the relevant remove link.

Comment: You can either wrap what you want to remove in an element, such as `<span>`, and then remove... **or** parse `.text()` from the div, remove the text, and set its `.text()` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var str = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.list').text($('.list').text().replace(str,''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUure/

But if you really need commas removed, you need to be a bit more creative:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var str = $(this).attr("class");
    var rgx = new RegExp(str + ',?\\s*');
    $('.list').text($('.list').text().replace(rgx,''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUure/4/

Comment: To include the comma, you will need a regex. `var rgx = new RegExp(str + '[,\\s]*');` http://jsfiddle.net/PUure/1/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Updated for (lazily) removing trailing commas without regex ;)

Check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/997z3/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('div.list').html($('div.list').html().replace($(this).attr('class') + ', ', '').replace($(this).attr('class'), ''));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var word = $(this).attr('class');
    var div = $('.list').text();
    div = div.replace(word, '');
        $('.list').text(div );

});
```

fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/sysCc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var str = $(this).attr('class');
  var obj = $('.list');
  var currentText = obj.text();
  obj.text(currentText.replace(str,'');
});
```

or condensed:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('.list').text($('.list').text().replace($(this).attr('class'),''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off keeping the data in an array, then modifying that array and refreshing your `div` with the new data.

```
var data = ["Abc", "Test", "Ready"];
refresh();

$("#Abc").click(function() { remove("Abc") });
$("#Test").click(function() { remove("Test") });
$("#Ready").click(function() { remove("Ready") });

function refresh() {
    $("div").text(data.join(", "));
}

function remove(word) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(i, data[i], word, data[i] == word);
        if (data[i] == word)
            data.splice(i, 1);
    }
    console.log(data);
    refresh();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/dHp3b/